# Jquery Edit Div Content After Resizing The Div

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, resizable

I have a button which allows me to change an element from draggable to have contenteditable instead. The element is also initially resizable and I am attempting to remove the resizable ability before edting (the same as I do with draggable)- upon clicking the button. Please note the element has class "draggable" and so the initial ".draggable" here is just used to reference the element.

The problem that I am having, is that when I turn off "resizable" the element contains stretching squares around it similar to selecting an image (I forget what you call those square things) and therefore although the resize handle is gone the element cannot be edited and can still be resized with those square things. any one have any ideas?

```
 $("#edit").click(function(){
     $(".draggable").draggable( "disable" )
       $(".draggable").resizable("option", "disabled", True);
         $("div").get(0).contentEditable = "true"; 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `destroy` instead of `disable` and see if it works as you expect it to:

```
$("#edit").click(function(){
     $(".draggable").draggable("destroy");
     $(".draggable").resizable("destroy");
     $("div").get(0).contentEditable = "true"; 
});
```